# mongodb with Bindata UUID sharding key not sharding

Tags: mongodb, sharding, bson

My typical document is:

```
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5093c2fbf6c07ab5a3ac779b"), "msid" : BinData(3,"3xGNFeKqXR4Zx0Q+FgCviA=="), "mt" : ISODate("2010-01-01T03:41:07Z")}
```

I have 2 shards. "msid" is a UUID in binary form for space efficiency as recommended by the docs. But when msid was string sharding was working. Now only one shard gets popuplated.

```
mongos> sh.status()
--- Sharding Status --- 
  sharding version: { "_id" : 1, "version" : 3 }
  shards:
    {  "_id" : "shard0000",  "host" : "rs1/vserver-dev-2:37018,vserver-dev-3:37018" }
    {  "_id" : "shard0001",  "host" : "rs2/vserver-dev-2:47018,vserver-dev-3:47018" }
  databases:
    {  "_id" : "admin",  "partitioned" : false,  "primary" : "config" }
    {  "_id" : "test",  "partitioned" : false,  "primary" : "shard0000" }
    {  "_id" : "ifms",  "partitioned" : true,  "primary" : "shard0000" }
        ifms.measurement_event chunks:
                shard0000   1
            { "msid" : { $minKey : 1 } } -->> { "msid" : { $maxKey : 1 } } on : shard0000 Timestamp(1000, 0) 
    {  "_id" : "mongo",  "partitioned" : false,  "primary" : "shard0001" }
```

It seems there's something wrong with the min/max keys.

and chunks:

```
mongos> db.chunks.find().pretty()
{
    "_id" : "ifms.measurement_event-msid_MinKey",
    "lastmod" : Timestamp(1000, 0),
    "lastmodEpoch" : ObjectId("5093afb369b03db47a1311eb"),
    "ns" : "ifms.measurement_event",
    "min" : {
        "msid" : { $minKey : 1 }
    },
    "max" : {
        "msid" : { $maxKey : 1 }
    },
    "shard" : "shard0000"
}
```

The db has now about 100 milion documents of ~180bytes each.

Comment: oh my, why didn't I think of that! Damn. I had a 2-second delay between one of my servers (a replica arbiter) and this prevented the lock. Thanks Asya!. Which is strange because all servers are running chrony.

Comment: cool, glad you found the issue.  I know mongodb.org wiki recommends using ntp to sync all servers to same clock, but doesn't list possible problems not having that can cause...